# keyup prevent modifiers - vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
<input @keyup="fetchData(0)">
```

Is it possible to PREVENT modifiers (ctrl+win+cmd, etc) to work on keyup event? Just the letters and numbers.

My case: it's a name filter, when a user types a letter, list of names are updated corresponding to entered letter, but when a user presses ctrl, or ctrl+a it counts as keyup event also.

Comment: Change it to @input

Comment: You may have to check for the keycode combinations you want to blacklist inside `fetchData`. What is your exact use case for wanting to prevent the above, while allowing ctrl, and ctrl + a?

Comment: @MahmudAdam i meant, to prevent, sorry :)

Comment: Have you come up with a solution yet?

Comment: I'm gonna try `@input` that dziraf mentioned.

Comment: @dziraf what's the difference using @input? Could you explain, i couldn't find an explanation.

Comment: `input` event fires on input element's value change, `keyup` when you release a key, so it's no wonder that it was being launched when you pressed Ctrl and other keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the keyCode from the event and trigger the fetch data method only when it's a letter or number

```
<input @keyup="onKeyUp($event)">

...
methods: {
    conKeyUp(e) {
        if ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 90) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)) {
            // a-z or 0-9 or numpad 0 - 9
            this.fetchData();
        }
    },
    fetchData() {
        // Fetching data from server...
    }
}
```

An alternative method will be triggering the fetch data when the value of the field is changed like so:

```
<input v-model="myModel">

...
data: {
    myModel: null
},
watch: {
    myModel() {
        this.fetchData();
    }
},
methods: {
    fetchData() {
        // Fetching data from server...
    }
}
```